# how to fix the problem i blender when it cannot assign weights

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I have been trying to assign bones to my mesh, and Blender keeps giving an error that it cannot assign weights to my design. Why is this so, and how can I fix it? I am using the option with automatic weights, yet the heat is not showing in any area of the mesh.

Comment: U may have more than one armature,ie
Any new finger bones added newly from object mode,also check whether the naming both right and left sides are evenly matched